# it says Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to binaryTree.Node on line 62 .remove() function (highlighted)

Tags: java, frameworks, queue, binary-tree

here is the code. i've marked where i'm getting the error, the tutorial i'm following has the same code and it's working fine. when i checked the functions available in the queue interface in java collection frameworks, it's showing the return type of .remove() as object. am i using a different java version or what?

```
import java.util.*;

public class binaryTree{
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        
        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }

    static class BT{
        static int idx = -1;

        public static Node buildTree(int nodes[]){
            idx++;
            if(nodes[idx]==-1){
                return null;
            }

            Node newNode = new Node(nodes[idx]);
            newNode.left = buildTree(nodes);
            newNode.right = buildTree(nodes);
            return newNode;
        }
    }

    public static void preOrder(Node root){
        if(root==null) {System.out.println(-1); return;}

        System.out.println(root.data);
        preOrder(root.left);
        preOrder(root.right);
    }

    public static void inOrder(Node root){
        if(root==null) { System.out.println(-1); return;}

        inOrder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.data);
        inOrder(root.right);
    }

    public static void postOrder(Node root){
        if(root==null) {return;}

        postOrder(root.left);
        postOrder(root.right);
        System.out.println(root.data);
    }

    public static void levelOrder(Node root){
        if(root==null) return;
        Queue q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(root);
        q.add(null);

        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            Node currNode = q.remove();    //over here
            if(currNode==null){
                System.out.println();
                if(q.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }else{
                    q.add(null);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println(currNode+" ");
                if(currNode.left!=null)
                    q.add(currNode.left);
                if(currNode.right!=null)
                    q.add(currNode.right);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nodes[] = {1, 2, 4, -1, -1, 5, -1, -1, 3, -1, 6, -1, -1};
        BT tree = new BT();
        Node root = tree.buildTree(nodes);
        // System.out.println(root.data);
        // preOrder(root);
        // inOrder(root);
        // postOrder(root);
        levelOrder(root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Queue q = new LinkedList<>();
```

to

```
Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

The reason is that
`Queue q = new LinkedList<>()` is the same as `Queue<Object> = new LinkedList<>()`.  As a result, `q.remove()` expected return type is `Object` instead of `Node`.